# How to compress assets without Rails or Sprockets?

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, gzip, compass

I'm writing a Sinatra app and I'm quite tired of Sprockets (because it's hard to configure and doesn't support some libs). I'm thinking of moving to Compass for stylesheet management but I haven't found anything similar to it when it comes to scripts. Now I can manually compile coffeescript into Javascript and concatenate the resulting files, but how do I compress them for less size? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at Gulp. [Here is the good article](http://blog.arkency.com/2015/03/gulp-modern-approach-to-asset-pipeline-for-rails-developers/) about using Gulp with Rails (but it would work for Sinatra too).

Comment: Thank you! It even has a [neat example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-gzip/) of exactly what I need!